# Python inheritance - object has no attribute error

Tags: python, inheritance

I am experimenting with basic python inheritance with a Dog class that inherits from an Animal class. For some reason, my Dog object is not inheriting `name` correctly and I keep getting `AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute '_Dog__name'`. Does anyone know what might be going on? My code is below:

```
class Animal(object):
    __name = None #signifies lack of a value
    __height = 0
    __weight = 0
    __sound = 0

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__height = height
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__sound = sound


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):

        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)

        self.__owner = owner
        #self.__name = name this works if I uncomment this line.

    __owner = ""

    def toString(self):
        return "{} belongs to {}".format(self.__name, self.__owner)
        #return 'Sup dawg'

fido = Dog("Spot", 3, 4, "Woof", "John")

print(fido.toString())
```

Comment: **Do not** use double-underscore name mangling unless you understand what it is actually for! It is *not* the same thing as a "private" access modifier. Also, do not use class variables that you only shadow with instance variables. Python != Java

Comment: Do **not use this tutorial**. The person who made it clearly not a Python programmer, and is probably someone who writes lot's of Java code. I mean seriously, `toString`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of `__`-prefixed attribute names is to mangle them so that subclasses *cannot* easily access them, to prevent them from accidentally being overridden. The error message shows you how the parent class mangles the name, so you could use that directly:

```
def toString(self):
    return "{} belongs to {}".format(self._Dog__name, self.__owner)
```

but you really should just dispense with the prefix and use a regular name. Also, don't define a `toString` method; use `__str__` instead. The class-level initializers are also unnecessary.

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.sound = sound

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)
        self.owner = owner

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} belongs to {}".format(self.name, self.owner)

fido = Dog("Spot", 3, 4, "Woof", "John")
print(fido)  # print will convert fido to a string implicitly, using its __str__ method
```